# Force update size of canvas without changing child contents in WPF

Tags: wpf, canvas, resize, scrollviewer

I have implemented a class which extends `Canvas`, and uses an override of `MeasureOverride` to update the size based on the arrangement of the child objects on it.

The aim is to have draggable objects on the `Canvas` which can be dragged out of the visible area and have a `ScrollViewer` update accordingly.

My class overrides `OnMouseMove` to bring the element directly under the cursor to the top of other elements - rather than setting the Z index, I am doing this by removing the element from the `Children` of the `Canvas` which I've extended, then re-adding the element.

When dragging the element out of the visual area, scroll bars are shown correctly - I believe that the removal and re-adding of the object is triggering the size to be updated, as `MeasureOverride` is called in this condition.

I do not wish to have the `OnMouseMove` method move the element to the top, but I still want to have scroll bars display when the element is dragged out of the visual area.

How can I force the size of the canvas to be recalculated without changing the content of the `Children` of the `Canvas`?

Dragging is handled by detecting a click, storing the start point and the object directly under the cursor, and updating the location if the dragged element is not null when the mouse is moved - dragging is working correctly, but I can add the relevant sample code if necessary.

The code below is obfuscated:

My extended `Canvas` -

```
public class MyCanvas : Canvas {


    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e) {
        UIElement isOver = (UIElement)Mouse.DirectlyOver;
        BringToTop(isOver);


    }

    private void BringToTop(UIElement element) {
        this.Children.Remove(element);
        this.Children.Add(element);
    }

    public void AddRect(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        Rect r = new Rect();
        r.Width = width;
        r.Height = height;
        Canvas.SetTop(r, x);
        Canvas.SetLeft(r, y);
        Children.Add(r);
    }

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint) {

        if (InternalChildren.Count == 0) {
            return new Size(0,0);
        }


        base.MeasureOverride(constraint);
        double width = InternalChildren
            .OfType<UIElement>()
            .Max(i => i.DesiredSize.Width + (double)i.GetValue(LeftProperty));

        double height = InternalChildren
            .OfType<UIElement>()
            .Max(i => i.DesiredSize.Height + (double)i.GetValue(TopProperty));

        return new Size(width,height);
    }

}
```

My `MainWindow.xaml` creates a `ScrollViewer` in a `DockPanel` as shown -

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True" >

    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
        Name="scrollViewer">
    </ScrollViewer>

</DockPanel>
```

My `MainWindow.xaml.cs` adds my `MyCanvas` and inserts some `Rect`s as shown -

```
public MainWindow() {
    InitializeComponent();

    MyCanvas myCanvas = new MyCanvas();
    myCanvas.AddRect(10, 10, 100, 200);
    myCanvas.AddRect(50, 50, 100, 150);

    scrollViewer.Content = myCanvas;
}
```

Comment: As a note, you don't need to remove and add child elements for bringing them to top. Just set their `Panel.ZIndex` attached property.

Comment: @Clemens Which means I have to iterate though all objects to set their Z index when I bring one to the top, which I don't want to do. I also didn't ask about bringing items to the top, I need to know how to enforce the size update. To set the Z index, I have to have an initial Z index set when I add an element. I might change this, but getting the scrolling to work properly is my priority.

Comment: That's why "As a note".

Comment: @Clemens Fair enough. I elected not to handle the Z index as removing and re-adding will always bring the item to the top. Normally, I would set Z index if there's a chance I'd need to insert an item mid way through the Z order, but as I don't need to in this case, I've gone for the quickest option.

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody comes across this and has a similar issue, the resolution is to call `InvalidateMeasure()` in the mouse over method as below:

```
protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e) {
    //In this case, the class extends Canvas, so InvalidateMeasure can be 
    //called directly.
    InvalidateMeasure();

    //If using a named Canvas object (i.e. myCanvasObject), InvalidateMeasure
    //should be called on that object, not on the child objects
    myCanvasObject.InvalidateMeasure();
}
```